# Hyperledger Fabric Join peer with latest config

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

How can I join a channel with a peer, using the latest config block ?

The orderers in config block 0 do no longer exist, the dns names have changed.

When I fetch the latest config for the channel, and try to join with that I get the following error:

```
peer channel fetch config ...

peer channel join ...


Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: cannot create ledger from genesis block: Expected block number=0, received block number=11276)
command terminated with exit code 1
```

However when I fetch config block 0 and join, it does so succesfully, but the peer never 'syncs' up as it can't connect to the orderers (as they no longer exist under that domain)

```
peer channel fetch 0 ...

peer channel join ...

...
in logs

Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer-3.orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 [...]} {orderer-1.orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 [...]} {orderer-2.orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 [...]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with block `0` or `oldest`. As DNS names have changed, you have to make some trick.

**TRICK 1: Override name resolution in `/etc/hosts`**.

In your peer (inside the docker container itself), edit `/etc/hosts`.

First, get the new domain IP:

```sh
# apt update
# apt install dnsutils -y
host new.svc.cluster.local
```

Take note of the IP, let's say `X.Y.W.Z`.

Now, edit `/etc/hosts` inside the peer container and associate the new IP to the old domain:

```
X.Y.W.Z old.svc.cluster.local
```

Do it for every domain that has changed. Now you should be able to join. Even if the peer joint before, now it is able to synchronize. Whenever your peer container is relocated, `/etc/hosts` changes are lost, but it doesn't mind once it has been synchronized

An alternative trick would be to use iptables, but it is only useful if your old domain still resolves to an IP.